# How to disable past dates in iondatetimepicker in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, date, plugins, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic, I use the ion-date-time-picker plugin and I want to disable past dates in iondatetimepicker in ionic.

My problem is that I'm unable to disable the previous dates.

Please help me to find the solution.

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" ion-datetime-picker class="fromDate" ng-attr-placeholder="{{data.start_date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm'}}" ng-required="true" ng-model="data.start_date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can set it as below:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="2016" max="2020-10-31" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Refer to cocument:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#min-and-max-datetimes

Comment: I am using this plugin https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker.git so i want to disable previous dates by using this plugin. i tried using your code but its not working

Comment: <input readonly="readonly" type="text" ion-datetime-picker class="fromDate" ng-attr-placeholder="{{data.start_date | date:'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm'}}"  ng-required="true" ng-model="data.start_date" />. Here i have used ion-datetime-picker directive. i am able to select date and time and even i could able to store it. But the thing is i couldn't able to disable the previous dates in the picker

Comment: https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker#only-valid-attribute please add attribute as only-valid="{'outside': {'initial': '2016-04-09', 'final': '2016-06-15'}, 'inclusive': true}"

Comment: how you add the only-valid attribute? share the code

Answer (score 1):

Its simple,

```
<ion-item>
         <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
         <ion-icon slot="end" name="calendar"></ion-icon>
         <ion-datetime  [(ngModel)]="date"
                        [min]="date"
                       name="date"
                       required
                       #dateCtrl="ngModel"></ion-datetime>
       </ion-item>
```

In TS File, add this code above the constructor

```
date: String = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: but there is timezone diffrence between "new Date()" and "new Date().toISOString();" how u handled this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use min option in ionic. So you are able to select the date from 2016-10-31 only.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="2016-10-31" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by installing moment.js:

```
npm install moment --save
```

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Filter by Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDDD MMMM YYYY" min="{{displayDate}}"  [(ngModel)]="selectedDate">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

In your ts file, you will include the code below:

```
displayDate: any = moment().format();
```